# Cocos2d: CCCallFuncO with target as parent

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action, parent, target

I can't seem to get CCCallFuncO working with actionWithTarget set to (JoinedMapsLayer*)self.parent

JoinedMapsLayer is the parent node that a sprite class gets added to.

Inside the sprite class I have a method:

```
-(void) playAction:(NSString*)name withMessagePart:(NSString *)messagePart {

    id displayMessageBox = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:(JoinedMapsLayer*)self.parent
                                                selector:@selector(displayMessageBox:)
                                                 object:[NSString stringWithFormat:messagePart]];


    if([name isEqualToString:@"shiver"]){

        id a1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.05 position:ccp(self.sprite.position.x+2, self.sprite.position.y)];
        id a2 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.05 position:ccp(self.sprite.position.x-4, self.sprite.position.y)];
        id a3 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.05 position:ccp(self.sprite.position.x+4, self.sprite.position.y)];
        id a4 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.05 position:ccp(self.sprite.position.x-2, self.sprite.position.y)];
        [self.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:a1,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a2,a3,a4,displayMessageBox, nil]];

    }

    else if([name isEqualToString:@"spin"]){

        id a1 = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:.5 angle:360];
        [self.sprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:a1,displayMessageBox, nil]];

    }
}
```

It runs the actions just fine on the sprite, but I'm trying to get it to call a method in the parent node. I have a NSLog in there to check, and nothing happens. Any obvious reasons why?

In my parent node's init the class is added to a mutable array

```
HummingClass *hummingChar = [[HummingClass alloc] init];

            [characterArr addObject:hummingChar]
```

And I access the class later on like:

```
HummingClass *hummingChar = [characterArr objectAtIndex:interactionIndex];
```

Interesting thing is that it doesn't crash with self.parent, so I'm thinking I'm not pointing to the parent node correctly. In the objects header I have

```
#import "JoinedMapsLayer.h"
@class JoinedMapsLayer
```

edit: even if I do a regular method call like this, it won't work:

```
[(JoinedMapsLayer*)self.parent displayMessageBox:@"whatever"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of something awful forums.  If a sprite is added to an array, you have to assign the parent property manually.

In init in JoinedMapsLayer, I make a temporary pointer to an array index:

tempHummingChar.parent = self;